# cannot convert method group to func<long,bool>

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am trying to use fluentvalidation to validate pin to ensure what user type match with existing pin. AppDbContext is the context class which inherit from dbcontext (Entity Framework).  I have this syntax error while calling isOldPin method. If PinCodeOld datatype is string, this error doesn't appear. But if PinCodeOld datatype is long, this error appear.

```
 public class ChangePinValidator : AbstractValidator<VMPinChange>
{
    private readonly AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();
    public ChangePinValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(b => b.PinCodeOld).Must(isOldPin).WithMessage("Invalid current pin code.");
        RuleFor(b => b.PinCodeNew).Equal(b => b.PinCodeConfirmation)
            .WithMessage("New pin code is not same with confirmed new pin code.");
    }

    private bool isOldPin(string _currentPin)
    {
        bool isMatch = db.BankAccounts.Any(b => b.PinCode.Equals(_currentPin));

        return isMatch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
RuleFor(b => b.PinCodeOld).Must(isOldPin)
```

If `PinCodeOld` is a long, then the `Must` method is going to expect a method that takes a `long` value as input, but your method takes a `string`. If you need it to be `long` then you also need to change the `isOldPin` to take a `long`.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Just wondering how do I pass additional parameter in isOldPin method as the query need to also filter by BankAccountId?

Comment: You mean like `Must(p => isOldPin(p, bankAccountId)`?

Comment: Yeah, this is it. Thanks a lot.